# Interrupt on the XMEGA

Tags: c, interrupts, xmega, gpio-external-interrupt

I  have 3 buttons connected to  PIN1, PIN3, PIN5  of PORTA  of an XMEGA. If pushed they deliver a falling edge.
I'm try to generate interrupt using those buttons, I started with one, here is what I have done:

```
void buttonINT(){
    // PORTA 
    PORTA.PIN1CTRL = PORT_OPC_PULLUP_gc | PORT_ISC_FALLING_gc;
    PORTA.INT0MASK = PIN1_bm;
    PORTA.INTCTRL = PORT_INT0LVL0_bm;
    PMIC.CTRL = PMIC_LOLVLEN_bm;
    sei();
    }
ISR(PORTA_INT0_vect){
    printf(" INTERRUPT \n");
}
```

in the main I call `buttonINT()` once , but I get the message  all time printed?

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the interrupt flag in ISR(), something like:

```
PORTA.INT0FLAGS = PIN1_bm;
```

(I have not looked up the exact labels.)